# Correct way to display image through restAPI

Tags: symfony

I am currently trying to show profile pictures through rest API. 
I got it to work, but I got a feeling it is not the correct way to do it.

So, on in the API i got a controller:

```
public function getUserprofilepicAction(Request $request) {
    /**
    * Handle stuff
    */

    $file = $user->getWebPath();
    $type = 'image/jpeg';
    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
}
```

Now the API call is something like this:

```
<somesite>/api/user/userprofilepic.json?userId=84
```

And in order to view the image on the webpage:

```
<img src = <somesite>/app_dev.php/api/user/userprofilepic.json?userId=84>
```

So now I wonder, what exactly is the best practises regarding sending/viewing pictures through restAPI in symfony2.

-Cheers

Comment: you should just return the path and not the file, so you return the path and the img-tag reads the file

Comment: I tried return the webPath, being: 
"<long URL>\/UserBundle\/Entity\/..\/..\/..\/..\/profile\/uploads\/pictures\/623697e0b5da3e25b8e8b83ad40918acc4f8ba73.jpeg"
But the image wont show, maybe i am putting it in the <img src = " " > wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right in the controller.

1. Get the image
2. Get the type (and other information such as the length) -- always jpeg for you?
3. Set HTTP Headers (Content-Type and others)
4. Return binary data (the content of the file)

There are other ways to achieve that:

- Via base64 encoded string: If you want to return a string instead of binary data, you can encode your image as a base64 string and then send it over the network. The problem is the size of the response. A base64 encoded string is 33% bigger than the binary data.
- Via web path: If you want to avoid reading the image, send the binary everytime, you could just return the URL of the image (ex. http://example.com/u/img.jpeg) and let the client do the request. This way you don't have any business logic behind the action. Everytime someone wants the profile picture, he just needs to query the URL of yhe image. For this solution you need to upload your images in a public dir like `web/uploads/pics/`.

PS: I would do something like `<somesite>/api/user/84/profilepicture` for the routing, if you want to follow REST idea.

Comment: Great answer!
Follow up questions:
- Do you know what is most common, returning binary data or web path?. 
- About the jpeg, no its not always Jpeg, I just could not find out how to get the MIME type. 
- Could you maybe elaborate about the REST Idea? New to this REST thing. 
:)
Thank you for a good answer :)

Comment: I think the most used way is web path. You can use dedicated servers to deliver binary data such as image, movies, sound, etc. This way you can reduce the load on your "business logic" server. For instance you can use a CDN for your images and allow your users to get images faster -- To get the right MIME type you can use the [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) class from Sf. `$ufile = new UploadedFile($filePath, $name); $type = $ufile->getMimeType()`. It will try to guess the right mime type from the binary content.

Comment: In very very very brief (there is a lot of resources on the internet about REST), when dealing with resources on a REST architecture, you use collections and id as URI. For instance `users/1` will reference the user with the id 1. `users/1/friends` will reference the list of friends for the user 1. `users/1/friends/139` will reference the friend 139 for the user 1. `users/84/profilepic` could be a good solution to get the attribute "profilepic" of the user 84. Or `/profilepictures/84` if you want to get the picture with the id 84 (maybe not related to the user 84)

Comment: I appreciate your answer Litz. Thank you :)

Comment: @typo: You should consider using the [Response](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) class. You can return a Response object for every action with specific headers and content. [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html)

Comment: What would be the major differences between return the Response class and readfile($file); ? @Litz

Comment: You will follow the way Sf works :D. You have to create a new Response, set some headers, set the content to get_file_contents(file) and return the Response object. I am no expert, but I think there are things Sf do before sending the response and you may want to use one of these one day.