# How to persist and serve image files for fullstack webapp (Spring Boot JPA, REST, Vue.js)?

Tags: spring, image, rest, jpa

I'm trying to build a movie database single page application with vue.js and spring-boot. I use spring and jpa to easily map my objects to a database schema.

I would now like to add a movie poster for each movie but I am unsure about where to put the image files (database or filesystem and where exactly or rather what kind of folder structure and filenames i should give them)

Movie.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String director;
    private Date releaseDate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "MOVIE_GENRES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MOVIE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GENRE_ID"))
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();

    // TODO how to rename value column (CAST -> ACTOR_ID)
    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "ACTOR_ROLE")
    private Map<String, Actor> cast = new HashMap<>();


    // TODO add fields
    public Movie(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void addActor(String role, Actor actor) {
        cast.put(role, actor);
    }

    public void removeActor(String role) {
        cast.remove(role);
    }

    public void addGenre(Genre genre) {
        genres.add(genre);
    }

    public void removeGenre(Genre genre) {
        genres.remove(genre);
    }
}
```

Result from GET /api/movies/1

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "The Matrix",
    "director": null,
    "releaseDate": null,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Science Fiction"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Action"
        }
    ],
    "cast": {
        "Agent Smith": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Hugo Weaving",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "dateOfBirth": "1960-04-04"
        },
        "Morpheus": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Laurence Fishburne",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "dateOfBirth": "1961-07-30"
        },
        "Thomas A. Anderson / Neo": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Keanu Reeves",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "dateOfBirth": "1964-09-02"
        }
    }
}
```

If I load the image files into the Movie class as a byte array, they will get persistet into the database. This would mean that the whole byte array would be transfered over JSON if i GET /api/movies... for EVERY MOVIE. This sounds horrible to be honest.

Now I don't really know where I should put the image files, how to reference them in my movie class (as a path? an absolute path? only a filename or uuid which the frontend can load via a REST call to /api/posters/id?).

Comment: I suggest to handle the posters with a separate PosterController and JPA-Repo. GET /api/poster/1 ... You just put the posterID in the movie-JSON.
I would prefer storing in filesystem than putting into database, but thats philosophy. In every case you pipe the bytestream through the controller to the customer. I hope my 2 cents can help..

Comment: That seems to be the better solution. I've tried implementing this and stumbled across another question. Do I base64 string encode the bytearray before sending it out over the api or do I send the byte array and let the frontend do the base64 encoding. Or how do I use the byte array as and html img src?
Thanks.

Comment: Do the encoding on the server. It's the REST philosophy to have a stateless api and a stupid client who just requests to the server and shows the result. ;)
This might be helpfull too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757922/correct-way-to-display-image-through-restapi